# Array Index Error while swiping on the game

Tags: java, android, android-studio, game-development

I have this match 3 game, but if I swiping outside the game board this error showed to me and crush the app:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=11
```

I tried to fix this error but I don't know how to make it work when I touch outside the game board, is that way to make touch only inside the game board game or just a way to ignore this error when it's happing?

```
public void swap()
{
        if(swapIndex > 0)
        {
            switch (direction){
                case "right":
                    board[poseI][poseJ + 1].poseX -= cellWidth/ 8;
                    board[poseI][poseJ].poseX += cellWidth/ 8;
                    break;
                case "left":
                    board[poseI][poseJ - 1].poseX += cellWidth/ 8;
                    board[poseI][poseJ].poseX -= cellWidth/ 8;
                    break;
                case "up":
                    board[poseI - 1][poseJ].poseY += cellWidth/ 8;
                    board[poseI][poseJ].poseY -= cellWidth/ 8;
                    break;
                case "down":
                    board[poseI + 1][poseJ].poseY -= cellWidth/ 8;
                    board[poseI][poseJ].poseY += cellWidth/ 8;
                    break;
            }
            swapIndex--;
        }else {
            Candies candies;
            candies = board[poseI][poseJ];
            board[poseI][poseJ] = board[newPoseI][newPoseJ];
            board[newPoseI][newPoseJ] = candies;

            board[poseI][poseJ].poseX = (int) (poseJ * cellWidth + drawX);
            board[poseI][poseJ].poseY = (int) (poseI * cellWidth + drawY);
            board[newPoseI][newPoseJ].poseX = (int) (newPoseJ * cellWidth + drawX);
            board[newPoseI][newPoseJ].poseY = (int) (newPoseI * cellWidth + drawY);

            swapIndex = 8;

            if (gameState == GameState.swapping)
            {
                gameState = GameState.checkSwapping;
                // count user moves
                increaseUserMove();
            }else {
                gameState = GameState.nothing;
            }

        }
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); // Background Color

    // Create Game top Background
    canvas.drawBitmap(spriteSheet.topBG , 0, - cellWidth * 2, null);
    // Create Game bottom Background
    canvas.drawBitmap(spriteSheet.bottomBG , 0, drawY + cellWidth * 9, null);
    // Create Game middle Background
    canvas.drawBitmap(spriteSheet.bg_middle , 0, drawY, null);

    // Create Game Cells
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK); // cells color

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(0, drawY + (i * cellWidth), cellWidth * 10, drawY + (i * cellWidth), p);
            canvas.drawLine(j * cellWidth , drawY, j * cellWidth, drawY + cellWidth * 9, p);
        }
    }

    for (Candies[] candie: board)
    {
        for (Candies candies: candie)
        {
            candies.drawCandies(canvas, spriteSheet);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
        {
            candies.drawCandies(canvas, spriteSheet);
        }
    }

    //canvas.drawBitmap(spriteSheet.candiesBMP, candies.poseX, candies.poseY, null);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    final int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            oldX = event.getX();
            oldY = event.getY();
            poseI = (int) (oldY - drawY) / cellWidth;
            poseJ = (int) (oldX - drawX) / cellWidth;

            move = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(gameState == GameState.nothing)
            {
                float newX = event.getX();
                float newY = event.getY();
                float deltaX = Math.abs(newX - oldX);
                float deltaY = Math.abs(newY - oldY);

                if(move && deltaX > 30 || deltaY > 30)
                {
                    // check how many pixels our fingers moved
                    // if we moved our finger more than 30 pixels we start checking in which direction
                    move = false;

                    if (Math.abs(oldX- newX) > Math.abs(oldY - newY))
                    {
                        // if the first X touch - the end of the X touch is bigger than the
                        // first Y touch - the end of the touch Y so the direction is in the X direction
                        // now we will check which is bigger the oldX or newX for know if its left or right
                        if(newX > oldX)
                        {
                            direction = "right";
                            newPoseJ = (poseJ + 1);

                        }else {
                            direction = "left";
                            newPoseJ = (poseJ - 1);
                        }
                        newPoseI = poseI;
                    }
                    if (Math.abs(oldY - newY) > Math.abs(oldX - newX))
                    {
                        if(newY > oldY)
                        {
                            direction = "down";
                            newPoseI = (poseI + 1);
                        }else {
                            direction = "up";
                            newPoseI = (poseI - 1);
                        }
                        newPoseJ = poseJ;
                    }
                    gameState = GameState.swapping;
                }
            }
            break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The error and code are clear , the error in the Array index.

Comment: Try to debug it

Comment: so you don't know how to fix this error?